# Ionic2 rc0 and redux/redux-thunk - create redux store with AoT

Tags: angular, redux, ionic2, redux-thunk, rollupjs

Anyone has been able to build an app with *redux* and *redux-thunk*? In my case, it's working with `ionic serve` but failing with `npm run build`. I can't build for devices, it only works in browser.

I'm getting these ngc errors

> [19:25:46]  ngc: Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values
>   statically. Calling function 'createStore', function calls are not
>   supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference
>   to an exported function, resolving symbol AppModule in
>   c:/Ionic/ionic-redux-test/.tmp/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol
>   AppModule in c:/Ionic/ionic-redux-test/.tmp/app/app.module.ts
>       at simplifyInContext (c:\Ionic\ionic-redux-test\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\static_reflector.js:469:23)
>       at StaticReflector.simplify (c:\Ionic\ionic-redux-test\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\static_reflector.js:472:22)
>       at StaticReflector.annotations (c:\Ionic\ionic-redux-test\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\static_reflector.js:61:36)
>       at _loop_1 (c:\Ionic\ionic-redux-test\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:53:54)
>       at CodeGenerator.readFileMetadata (c:\Ionic\ionic-redux-test\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:66:13)
>       at c:\Ionic\ionic-redux-test\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:100:74
>       at Array.map (native)
>       at CodeGenerator.codegen (c:\Ionic\ionic-redux-test\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:100:35)
>       at codegen (c:\Ionic\ionic-redux-test\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js:7:81)
>       at Object.main (c:\Ionic\ionic-redux-test\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\main.js:30:16)
>
> [19:25:46]  ngc: Compilation failed
>
> [19:25:46]  ngc failed:  NGC encountered an error [19:25:46]  Error:
>   NGC encountered an error
>       at ChildProcess. (c:\Ionic\ionic-redux-test\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\ngc.js:62:24)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
>       at ChildProcess.cp.emit (c:\Ionic\ionic-redux-test\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:29)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5) Error running ionic app script
>   "build": Error: NGC encountered an error

These are the modifications I've made on **app.module.ts** just before @NgModule

```
//Redux - ReduxThunk - rootReducer
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk  from 'redux-thunk';
import { rootReducer } from '../modules/rootReducer';

const appStore = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
);
```

And adding this in the providers array:

```
providers: [
    { provide: 'AppStore', useValue: appStore }
]
```

Edit: After these changes in **app.module.ts** and turning *const appStore* into an *export function*.

```
export function appStore(): any {
  return createStore(
            rootReducer,
            applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
          );
};
```

I'm able to compile and run the project but then getting this error in home.ts

> this.appStore.getState is not a function TypeError:
>
> this.appStore.getState is not a function

This is what I have in home.ts

```
export class HomePage {
    constructor(
        @Inject('AppStore') public appStore: any,
    ) { }

testRedux(){
    this.appStore.dispatch((dispatch)=> {
        dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'});});
    console.log(this.appStore.getState().increment.counter);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it with the following change in *app.module.ts*

```
// const appStore = createStore(
//   rootReducer,
//   applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
// );

export function appStore(): any {
  return createStore(
            rootReducer,
            applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
          );
};
```

Edit: by changing *useValue* to *useFactory* in the provider array. It'll solve the second issue.

```
  providers: [
    { provide: 'AppStore', useFactory: appStore }
  ]
```

Comment: Pretty sure const is a es6 and ngc transpiler is es6 and this is why you have this work around